# Would it be better to use Knockout.js in this situation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, dom, knockout.js

I'm currently developing a rather large analytic program with a Django/Python backend and am using jQuery.

Let's say that all of my statistics are based on the concept of a "`Person`". After viewing overview statistics, someone may want to open up an individual `Person` and look at their statistics.

Currently I send an AJAX request back to my server, Django fetches the person, renders an entire DOM Tree for them, and returns it. jQuery takes the returned `<div>` and adds it to the documents DOM tree along side any other opened people.

So every `Person` has their own div with all of the same elements, just with their information. The current person you're viewing is `display:block;` while I `display:none;` any other people. Any elements (such as a button to view more detailed information) that need to go back to the server to fetch more detailed information are coded with Django's templating system and given an onlick of something like `getMoreInformation('myUUID');`. I would also like to note that I find myself using UUID's in element IDs frequently so AJAX can find and modify the right person's information if need be.

I recently discovered Knockout.js and am wondering if it would be better for me to use it in this situation, and have some concerns about speed, etc.

It seems like Knockout.js would be "the right thing to do" as it provides a better 1-to-1 relationship between data on the backend and how it is represented in the Javascript (models to models) instead of individual DOM elements with ids passed for any functions. Not to mention it would drastically reduce the amount of elements in the DOM tree.

However, my primary audience is IE8, and I have concerns on Knockout.js having performance problems. While currently I just hide and show the divs related to the people you're investigating, Knockout.js would have to go through all of the `data-bind`'s and use Javascript to replace their content.

What are the performance concerns for using Knockout.js in a situation like this? Or would they be so minimal as to not matter? Hard a hard time finding any benchmarks, has anyone experienced slower UI when moving to Knockout.js? (Less DOM Elements + Knockout.js vs. More DOM Elements w/o Knockout.js in a "real world" application is kind of what I'm looking for here.)

Comment: is knockout.js better than... what? there's nothing to compare to.

Comment: @KevinB Would it be better than what I am currently doing (the first 4 paragraphs)?

Answer (score 1):

I think knockout would be great for this,  remember you can just use the visible binding to set `display: none` so it isn't bad.  Also, as per performance, it will likely do as good or better than jQuery since the binding has direct access to the element and doesn't need to query the DOM.

There may be a fair bit of work involved though, if your server is returning html. You would instead want it to return the data as JSON and build the UI in the browser.  Also unless you want individual values to update after they are loaded into view, you probably don't even need the individual bits of data to be observables.

I don't see why you think there would be more or less DOM elements by switching to knockout.  Knockout uses templates which don't need to be in the DOM prior to rendering.
Your current implementation is inserting chunks of html into the DOM and all else being equal they should be the same.

Comment: Yes the bindings have the element they're bound to as a local variable

Comment: Currently there is an entire DOM tree for every person. To my understanding, I would have one section of HTML that would be linked to currentPerson which is a member of a People array? Therefore if I just set currentPerson to a different person, the HTML is updated to reflect that persons information. You would still use templates and have an entire tree for each person (instead of the currentPerson method)? Interesting that you mention the binding doesn't need to query the DOM, I was unaware of that. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewKremer: You only have dom elements for what is being shown at the current time. All your 'people' are stored in javascript, and then the html is created for each person only when you use them in a binding that displays their info. You aren't storing a dom tree for each person, unless you want to display all people at once.

Comment: @wired_in Correct, I was questioning the last paragraph in this answer. I agree with you. Is having Knockout.js have to go through one dom tree and replace with the current persons information slower than having 5, 10, 20+ different dom tree's that I just switch between is kind of what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: If theres alot of logic to building the person node it could be slower than just slapping ready made html into a div, but I dont think it will be noticable.  Also consider you are offloading processing burden to the browser instead of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment but comment was too long so here is an answer

[Optimizing performance of data visualisation web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011253/optimizing-performance-of-data-visualisation-web-application)

I've changed a data visualization tool after having a similar thinking;

it used to call a lot the server at every interaction,

now the server send lots of data & js is doing the rest;

i set index upon reception of data (up to 170kb ungzipped), then depending on user interaction dom is modified (no display:none all over the place, content are changed or detached; data is store in javascript array not in html elements)

result is amazingly fast (i was surprise);

you have to be carefull the way you append your element to the DOM, to create well structured object to access the least the DOM;

dunno about knockout but imo if it's big & specific & you look for performance you'd better do the algorithm yourself (it's not that hard just process your data into indexed arrays that will be used as is when events are triggered - ie one loop at reception, no more)

Comment: Thanks for the link, we used to do more on the client side, however we analyze an very large amount of data, so we determined it was much much more efficient to send only data that was needed. Will definitely look at that question though, thanks!

Comment: your js/jquery was probably not optimized nor well designed, & you say you were keeping data in dom / bad. sending so many request is not efficient whatsoever. (we are dealing for 5mb+ of raw data in this project & found efficiency by moving most of the job from server to client - was thinking like you before & i was wrong !)