# php, ajax : Is it better to load everything at the beginning if possible?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a website with only one page. On this page, i can click on images and i show or hide popup (with jquery).

It works fine.

All these popup contains text, images (i use php to generate this content).

```
<div id="pop_up_1>
    <!-- content : text / images -->
<div/>
<div id="pop_up_2>
    <!-- content : text / images -->
<div/>
and so on
```

It's like i have 10 pages inside one page. It's a lot of content.

Do you think it's better to load everything at the beginning or load the content with jquery ajax :

```
$("#myDiv").load("ajax/video-mur-images.php");
```

I've tested the 2 solutions and i'm not sure which one to choose.

The first one : everything is loaded and no more query after but a lot of source code and elements.

The 2nd one, less elements and less source code but i have to load the content when the user click on a button.

I guess it depends on how much data i need to load. So what is the limit i should consider ?

Comment: loading up to 170kb before gzip more possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011253/optimizing-performance-of-data-visualisation-web-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting philosophical question. Often, as you do now, developers start with data volume, but in the end it's all about user experience.

Does your page load slowly? If so, have followed the [best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) to speed up page loads? And what would annoy the user more -- initial load or to have to wait on each interaction?

Also note that while web crawlers for search engines are getting better, they do not load your AJAX content. When you decide to go on this path, use a framework that gives you bookmark capability and also makes internal links understandable to the crawlers.

Comment: The site doesn't load slowly but i try to optimize. I didn't know that ajax content was not crawled so it's a very important point. You're right about user experience. I guess i should use ajax only when divs contain a lot of data.

Comment: PJAX makes your pages crawlable while using AJAX to load them. See http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely better to use AJAX (or even better PJAX) to load the content. Simply because you don't know how many pages there will be in the future. Serving all pages in a single request means that you might do 50 database queries, while the user only needed the page that does 0 queries.

Comment: so wrong except if you don't know how to write a query nor cache a query result; every request is at least 2 seconds waiting for the content then the client has to ungzip & process the data; which it would do just once if you send as much data as possible, with nowaday connection additional waiting time for 15 kbgzip vs 1kbgzip is hardly noticeable

Comment: @mikakun It's not about the download size or time. It's about performing operations like database queries unnecessarily.

Comment: correct...  if you don't know how to write a sql query nor cache a query result on the server;

Comment: Database queries was just an example. Plus you assume the OP uses a cache, which is a topic on its own. Point of my answer is that you're wastefully doing more operations on the server (asking the cache counts as an operation), than the user has asked for.

Comment: in fact much more like way less  connections & queries if you load all at once with a nicely written sql query & one only (which is always possible except if every page was a data visualization tool on its own) : one for all vs one at each request + the sending/connection/receiving at every request (i use to balance most of the job server side as you suggest but i realize i was plain wrong)

Comment: did you test both solutions with users/ram usage/server usage/bandwidth/number of database connection ? I did ajax only wins in ram usage & it doesn't affect client whatsoever. And for the users & editors experience there is no way they would go back to one ajax/interaction huge difference they say.